# Onlclick event not working when appended

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append an onclick event however, its not working. It works fine within html though

```
var a = $("#testappendid").append('<div id="imagewrap"><a href="" id="infobutton" onclick="alert("test");"></a></div>');

 var b = $("#testappendid").append('<div id="imagewrap"><a href="" id="infobutton" onclick="RedirectInformation();"></a></div>');

function RedirectInformation() {
 alert("test");
  }
```

Comment: Why do you appending elements with the same ID??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `click` event handler for elements added `dynamically` using `.on` method.

```
$(document).on('click','#infobutton',function(){
    //code here.
});
```

Read more about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Further more, you've tried to assign same `id` for two elements and that's a wrong way:the `id` attribute must pe unique.